# Cross Browser Jsonp request issues

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jsonp

Okay so I have a php function func4.php that i need to acces it from any server:

```
 <?php

      include'includes/connect.php';

$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `c_clicks`");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
$clicks = $row['id'];


}
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{\"clicks\":".$clicks."}" . ')';
 mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

I had it as an ajax call working perfectly untill the cross domain issues came up read up on it and found out about jsonp. I tried to implement it in my own script but ive failed.
here is what i attempted:

```
var security = function(){
var link = $('link').attr("href");
$.getJSON("http://www.groupon.com-fit.us/test/func4.php?callback=?",
 function(res){
  alert('the result is ' +res);
 }
);
};
```

I am very new to this and sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: You need to first call that from the location bar. You are also not passing anything to the server that might result in a valid response. Also you have a breakline in your URL

Comment: you STILL have a breakline in your URL and you are not doing anything on the server with the data passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First debug your server call by calling it from location bar and looking at the headers
- strange PHP you loop but only return the last result. If there is only one result don't loop.
- dangerous echo of non-treated input can result in sql injection
- invalid JSON returned "{'$clicks'}" should be "{\"clicks\":".$clicks."}" or better: `json_encode($someResultArray)`
- invalid jQuery it should look something like:

.

```
var security = function(){
   $.getJSON("http://www.mysit.com/test/func4.php?callback=?",
     function(res){
      alert('the result is ' +res.clicks);
     }
   );
};
```

Comment: My bad but would you look at my updated code i am very new to this and still a bit confused with the concept

Comment: So echo some more stuff

Comment: so once i get it so i when i put it in the location bar and it returns a number its gonna work?

Comment: i tried echo $clicks; didnt work eithe but if i remove the callback echo it works

Comment: with just the callback echo its showing me this now :({"clicks":47})

Comment: where php or the .getjson request?

Comment: whats the {"link":link} where did you get that from or what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

`{'anything'}` is not JSON.

1. Do [validate your JSON](http://jsonlint.com)
2. Don't generate JSON by mashing together strings, use a well-tested [library function](http://php.net/json_encode)

Comment: what do you mean by {'anything'}

Comment: "{'$clicks'}"  should be "{\"clicks\":".$clicks."}"

Comment: anything means anything. Whatever the value of `$clicks` is, it won't make it valid.

Comment: Not without more work, since JSON requires the outside layer be an array or an object, not a string or a number.

Comment: yo im sorry with all the questions i updated with what you guys told me but still no good. What else is wrong? im guessing its this {"clicks":clicks,"callback":"?"}